# Compiler variance for the type of deduced (non-type) template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang, language-lawyer

Consider the following example:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A {};

template <A const i> void f() { 
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(i), A const>);  // #1
    A& ar = i;                                            // #2
}

int main() {    
    f<A{}>();
}
```

which both Clang<sup>(1)</sup> and GCC<sup>(1)</sup> rejects with the following two seemingly conflicting errors:

> ```
> #1 error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'std::is_same_v<A, const A>'
> #2 error: binding reference of type 'A' to value of type 'const A' drops 'const' qualifier
> ```

[GCC demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aOjrRkQ4FuydniqB), [Clang demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Vz16aWSFBFwEU33h).

Moreover, if we change the type of the non-type template parameter into a placeholder type as follows:

```
template <auto const i> void g() { 
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(i), A const>);  // #1
    A& ar = i;                                            // #2
}
```

Then GCC accepts `#1`, whereas Clang rejects it (both reject `#2` as above).

[GCC demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WHKw4Mdqu0MG6VCJ), [Clang demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xk2uI9knsT7I2FcU).

What is going on here, and which compiler is correct (if any)?

---

<sub>(1) GCC HEAD 11.0.0 20210117 and Clang HEAD 12.0.0 (20210118), `-std=c++20`.</sub>

Comment: It would be great if you'd link godbolt examples of the problem, as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both GCC and Clang are (probably) correct to emit errors for both `#1` and `#2` for `f`.

As per [[temp.param]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.param#6.sentence-2) [**emphasis** mine]:

> A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following
> (possibly cv-qualified) types:
>
> - (6.1) **a structural type** (see below),
> - (6.2) a type that contains a placeholder type ([dcl.spec.auto]), or
> - (6.3) a placeholder for a deduced class type ([dcl.type.class.deduct]).
>
> The top-level cv-qualifiers on the template-parameter **are ignored
> when determining its type.**

the top-level cv-qualifiers are ignored *when determining its type*; it's arguably somewhat vague what "determining" refers to for (6.1), as compared to (6.2) and (6.3) which deals with placeholder types that need to be deduced.

[[dcl.type.decltype]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.type.decltype#1) [**emphasis** mine]:

> For an expression `E`, the type denoted by `decltype(E)` is defined as
> follows:
>
> - [...]
> - otherwise, if `E` is an unparenthesized id-expression naming a non-type template-parameter, `decltype(E)` **is the type of the
>   template-parameter after performing **any** necessary type deduction**
>   ([dcl.spec.auto], [dcl.type.class.deduct]);
> - [...]

mentions that the type of `decltype(i)` in `f` is the type of the non-type template parameter, after performing *any* necessary type deduction, followed by two references that connect to [temp.param]/6.2 and [temp.param]/6.3.

The key for `#1` in `f` is thus whether or not [temp.param]/6.1 also undergoes "determining of its type", even when its clearly been annotated as `A const` (no deduction needed). Both GCC and Clang seems to agree that this is the case: `A const` undergoes "determining of type" and `const` is removed.

---

Understanding `#2` in `f` is more straightforward; the actual *template parameter object* associated with the non-type template parameter (of class type) `A` is not necessarily the same type as non-type template parameter; instead its type is governed by [[temp.param]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.param#8) [**emphasis** mine]:

> An *id-expression* naming a non-type template-parameter **of class type** `T` denotes a static storage duration object **of type `const T`, known as a *template parameter object***, whose value is that of the corresponding template argument after it has been converted to the type of the template-parameter. All such template parameters in the program of the same type with the same value denote the same template parameter object. A template parameter object shall have constant destruction ([expr.const]). [ *Note:* If an id-expression names a non-type non-reference template-parameter, then it is a prvalue if it has non-class type. Otherwise, if it is of class type T, it is an lvalue and has type const T ([expr.prim.id.unqual]). — *end note* ]

such that that the *template parameter object* for any class type `T` always have the type `const T`, thus explaining the error at `#2`. Note that the latter only holds for class types, as an id-expression naming a non-type non-reference template_parameter is a prvalue.

---

As for the discrepancy between GCC and Clang at `#1` in `g`, there is no vagueness when applying [temp.param]/6 , particularly [temp.param]/6.2, applying type deduction whilst ignoring the cv-qualifiers on the template-parameter. Meaning `decltype(i)` is `A` in `g`, and GCC is wrong to accept line `#1`. I have filed the following GCC bug report accordingly:

- [Bug 98820 - Placeholder (auto) non-type template parameter wrongly deduced to 'const' for class type arguments](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=98820)